# How to programmatically get connection string from local database at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, localdb

I have created a local DB programmatically using Winforms (c#) and added tables, stored procedures to it, and stored on the user's preferable location. Now, all I want is to make my Winforms app access it using without opening visual studio or SSMS to get the connection string for that database.

**My try:**
I did open the visual studio to get the database's connection string to add it to the WinForms app's connection string and I want to make transactions with it.

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the connection string of the user-selected database from the Winforms application?

Like,

1. User chooses the location of already created localdatabase.mdf from his WinForms app.
2. The application retrieves the connection string so that he can use it to connect to the database.

The retrieval can be of parts like only retrieving the `Data Source` for the database. I can manage to build the connection string with it. Like using the name of the file for `Initial Catalog` and adding `Integrated security` using strings.

Comment: So you want to query something from the DB before connecting to it...? Does this make any sense? Or do I misunderstand something here...? Connection string is the key to access, so you need to know it. It has a pattern, replace the variables in it, like DB-Location, Security, etc, and you're good to go

Comment: @dba, I have created the database which sits on `master` which has connection string =>`Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master` after this I want to connect to the created localDB which has connection string of `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyAppDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True`. But for this, I cannot get the connection string of local DB the app programmatically created as the app will not be under any IDE(released) and it should be able to get the connection string without using any IDE as the user is a non-tech person. So, I hope you understand

Comment: Why do you think a LocalDB is something that only exists inside visual studio? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Caius Jard Yeah, I'm meaning any IDE or SSMS for LocalDB. The app itself gets the connection string from the database which is programmatically created by the same app and gets used and maintained connected for further transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and edit the connection string using [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) Class.

Here the connection string is local to the method but any place in scope of the method below.

```
public static void ChangeConnectionStringFromExisting()
{

    var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master";

    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

    builder.DataSource = "(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "MyAppDatabase.mdf";

    connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // . . .
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you specify how to get the `DataSource` if the database is on `Primary`? @KarenPayne

Comment: Even though the database is programmatically created as localdb I cannot access it like `service-based database`. And it shows Exception as => Cannot open database "C:\MyAppDatabase.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'OpusCorpus\OpusCorpus

Comment: try this connectionstring, replace `{databaseLocation}` with the full path to the mdf - which the user selects by your app -`$@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename={databaseLocation}; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30"`